# Observe only one WorkRequest in a chained Work Continuation

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have a set of chained work requests, and I want to observe only the first one of them.

I get the `LiveData` using a unique tag assigned to only the first request. Inside the filter, I again filter the `List<WorkInfo>` for the worker tag.

Despite all the filtering, I get *three* success notifications, one for each successful work request in the chain, even though the tag was added only to the first request.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or is it the expected behaviour (tag is assigned to all work requests in a chain).

Is there a way to observe only one of the work requests in a chain?

My code so far:

```
val workerTag = "a randomly generated long string"

val syncRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SyncWorker>()
    .setConstraints(syncConstraints)
    .addTag(workerTag)
    .build()

val followOnRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FollowOnWorker>()
    .build()


val finalRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FinalWorker>()
    .build()


WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    .beginUniqueWork(WORK_ONE_TIME_SYNC, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncRequest)
    .then(followOnRequest)
    .then(finalRequest)
    .enqueue()

WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    .getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(workerTag)
    .observe(this, Observer { workInfoList ->

        val workInfo = workInfoList.find { it.tags.contains(workerTag) }
            ?: return@Observer

        // THIS OBSERVER IS CALLED FOR ALL THE REQUESTS IN THE CHAIN ABOVE WITH ALL THE TAGS 
        if (workInfo.state.isFinished) {
            Timber.i(workInfo.tags.joinToString(", "))
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended.  If you need to get the `WorkInfo` for only one `WorkRequest`, you can do so by its `id` or this way:

```
val continuation = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    .beginUniqueWork(WORK_ONE_TIME_SYNC, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncRequest)
continuation.then(followOnRequest)
    .then(finalRequest)
    .enqueue()

continuation.getWorkInfosLiveData()
    .observe(this, Observer { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll test it out.

Comment: Nope. Still the same. The observer is still triggered multiple times—once for each workRequest in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to observe the first request, rather then use `continuation.getWorkInfosLiveData()` you can just use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(java.util.UUID) and thus your code changes to:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    .getWorkInfosByIdLiveData(syncRequest.id)
    .observe(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I'll give it a try. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Rahul. Sadly, this doesn't work either. The observer is still called for all the following requests in the chain.